# Input inside form to cover all the background

Tags: html, css, button, background, cover

Now I got the following [**page**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zdyq/)

I want the orange button to cover all the white background,like here:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove  `padding: .5em` from the form and what you want to make is I assume input field text to be centered that you can do by changing the `padding` of `input[type="website"]` field and this is the result [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zdyq/5/)

For your reference I've used `padding` like this :

`padding: .4em .3em .3em .7em;`

is nothing but

```
padding-top: .4em;
padding-right: .3em;
padding-bottom: .3em;
padding-left: .7em;
```

It's called CSS short hand property, you can get more like these over **[here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200502/efficient_css_with_shorthand_properties/)**

Comment: Thanks,just one more thing.How can I make the whole box a little bit more to the right so it can be aligned with the logo and the second heading?

Comment: sorry I didn't understood, which logo you are talking about? the 1 which you recently floated left?

Comment: @SixQuads I would like to recommend you to try first so you'll understand the concepts better

Answer (score 0):

Your form has 0.5em padding on it (that white space), make that padding:0px; and your set

http://jsfiddle.net/8zdyq/2/

Comment: Thanks,but that makes the text not to be centered.
Is there any solution for that?